# MySQL trigger: turn UPDATE into UPDATE and INSERT?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have several tables that I want to enforce versioning, and have an effective from and effective to date. Whenever an application or user writes an UPDATE to this table I want it redirected into two entirely new commands: UPDATE the targeted record so the EFFECTIVE_TO date is populated with current date and time, and INSERT an entirely new record with the updated attributes.

Is this possible to do with a trigger or do I have to keep controlling this externally with a Java application?

Comment: You want to update and insert into the same table? will it not duplicate the records?

Comment: Yes. But the inserted record will be the current record with new values and an effective_to of 12-31-2099. The old record will be updated with the current date which effectively discontinues it. This is to keep track of changes and see history.

Comment: yes you can do it using trigger but I would suggest maintaining two separate table (current / history).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this probably

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER versioningcontrol AFTER UPDATE ON yourtable
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO yourtable(col1,col2,...) values(...);
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```